# Typescript: How to use `extends` in certain circumstances

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two interfaces:

```
interface Person {
    name:string,
    active:boolean,
    id:number,
    location?:string
}

 interface Department {
    company:string,
    department:string
}
```

I use the `Person` interface once here:

```
const mycontact:Person = {
    name: 'John',
    active: true,
    id: 1
}
```

But in the same script I want to use both the `Person` and `Department` interface together but only here with the `myPeeps` variable. When I try to use the `extends` keyword I get an error: `'?' expected` Is it possible to only use `extends` in certain circumstances? If so how is that done?

```
const myPeeps:Person extends Department[] = [
    {name: 'A', active: true, id: 1, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'C', active: true, id: 2, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'D', active: true, id: 3, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'K', active: true, id: 4, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'T', active: true, id: 5, location: 'cali', company:'', department: ''}
]
```

Comment: extends is meant for `classes` and `interfaces`. You want a type intersection `&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case use the `&` operator to satisfy both interfaces

```
const myPeeps: (Person & Department)[] = [
    {name: 'A', active: true, id: 1, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'C', active: true, id: 2, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'D', active: true, id: 3, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'K', active: true, id: 4, company:'', department: ''},
    {name: 'T', active: true, id: 5, location: 'cali', company:'', department: ''}
]
```

[image]